# Do rolls other than talent/skill/attribute tests explode?

Tags: earthdawn-1e

I know for a fact that when you roll the max on a dice, you get to reroll and add the new result.

Is this mechanic only used on talent/skill/attribute tests or is it also used for damage rolls, effects rolls and recovery rolls?

I use First Ed and use some references to third Ed and classic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you do. They are in fact Tests and the same rule applies.

In *Game Concepts, Make a Test section* it says that ever time you roll dice to resolve an action, these are called ***Action Dice*** and this is called ***Rolling a Test***. Every time you roll Action Dice you get a Bonus dice on rolling a maximum.

Recovery Rolls are in fact Recovery **Tests** in the same section and see in the Combat Section under Recovering from Damage.

Damage Roll are called Damage **Tests** see in the Combat Section, Making a Damage Test.

Spell and Talent Effects are sometimes things like Willforce or Charisma, using a Talent, Skill or Attribute is always a Test. And hence in these case it is also true.

In fact just about any time you roll dice it is a Test and the bonus rule applies.

Comment: In Earthdawn everything explodes!

Comment: Pretty much yes. We did find an example where it did not but I can't remember it at the mo.